# How to make Angularjs nested routes?

Tags: javascript, url-routing, angularjs

I am new to angular, I want to know if angularjs supports nested routes like emberjs I mean routes like this: `myappurl/#/company/:company_id/department/:department_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the example given in the document: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView.  Yes, Angularjs supports it.

Comment: Thank you so much the frontend developer in my team was very happy :) we missed it.

Answer (score 7):

It worth mentioning there are another Angular libraries except `ui-router` to accomplish this task. This one works too:

http://angular-route-segment.com

It is much simpler to use than ui-router. Sample route configuration looks like this:

```
$routeSegmentProvider.

when('/section1',          's1.home').
when('/section1/prefs',    's1.prefs').
when('/section1/:id',      's1.itemInfo.overview').
when('/section1/:id/edit', 's1.itemInfo.edit').
when('/section2',          's2').

segment('s1', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section1.html',
    controller: MainCtrl}).

within().

    segment('home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/home.html'}).

    segment('itemInfo', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item.html',
        controller: Section1ItemCtrl,
        dependencies: ['id']}).

    within().

        segment('overview', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item/overview.html'}).

        segment('edit', {
             templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item/edit.html'}).

        up().

    segment('prefs', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/prefs.html'}).

    up().

segment('s2', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section2.html',
    controller: MainCtrl});
```

Comment: In the example, would section.html ever be hit?  `/section1` is routed to the s1 .. home segment, right?  If I'm right, it is misleading to have a templateUrl defined in the s1 segment.  Then the question... does the `MainCtrl` for the s1 segment become a parent controller to the `Section1ItemCtrl`?

Comment: It is a nested view hierarchy. `home.html` is included into `section1.html`, and so forth. All controllers are inside a prototypal scope chain. You can see this example live here: http://angular-route-segment.com/src/example/

Comment: @artch how can u do this? I go Section1, then i go to Item 5 (inside section1), now i go to Section2, now i click on Section1(it reestar pages, BUT I WAMMA REOPEN ITEM5) im not sure if u understand what im saying

Answer (score 3):

It can also be worth checking out https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router