# Embedding a view in another view using Angular and ng-route

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am making front-end in Angualr and backend in Rails. I would like to embed a view in another view. Below structure is what i'm currently doing.

```
//index.html
<head>
<scrip src="path/MainController.js"></script>
<scrip src="path/controller1.js"></script>
<scrip src="path/controller2.js"></script>
<head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>

//app.js
var app;
app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/page1', {
                templateUrl: 'path/page1.html',
                controller: 'controller1'
            }).when('page2', {
            templateUrl: 'path/page2.html',
            controller: 'controller2'
        })
}]);
```

Right not, I am trying to embed page2.html into page1.html. I can copy & paste the code of page2.html into page1.html but I would like to keep the views separate. controller1 is needed for page1.html and controller2 is needed for page2.html. This means that I need to load controller2 into page1.html somehow too.

I would love to know how I can achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

U can follow this way include the page2.html inside the page.html using **ng-include**

**Page1.html**

```
<div id="page-wrapper">        
    <div class=" ng-include="'views/common/Page2.html'" ng-controller="PagesecondController"></div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper" ui-view></div>
</div>
```

for reference http://embed.plnkr.co/pARExi/

Comment: This is not loading any view if I do this way. Do I need to configure something else?

Comment: Do I need to inject dependency to the app or something in order to use ng-include?

Comment: did u check the plunker i gave ?  angular-route have u include ? and version of angular check

Comment: I did exactly what you did except the version of angular and angular-route. What you used is very old. I think angular is on 1.5.x or 1.4.x or something

Comment: whats your version

Comment: I have 1.5.3 angular and angular route.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How to make Angularjs nested routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790075/how-to-make-angularjs-nested-routes). It shows an example of creating nested routes, which will let you embed page2 into page1.